# Ubuntu updates: automatic vs. command line seem to be different in results

Tags: updates

I noticed (for quite a while, but currently using Ubuntu 18.04) that the automatic update works well, but once it's finished I can go to the command line and use sudo apt update and there are packages that can be updated.

Is this due to a setting I can change in the automatic update, or is it just the way the automatic update works? (In other words it only updates certain things.)

Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting of unattended-upgrades is to use only the -security pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. Not -upgrades, not -backports, not Canonical Partners, not PPAs or other non-Ubuntu repositories.

You can change this setting in the config file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`